# How to create three-way interaction graph in R (I have example of graph)?

Tags: r, interaction

I would like to create this kind of graph for my data (categorical IVs and continuous DV). How can I find the formula that helps me to run this?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but, as an aside, I think a parallel box plot would be better than a dynamite graph. Or, if N isn't large, a parallel strip plot.

Comment: I can do a parallel box plot as well. Do you have any idea how to do it in R?

Comment: I moved the question to StackOverflow, the site about programming questions. Likely someone there will know.

Comment: Thank you Peter Flom. ^^

Comment: Link to or paste of sample data pls

Comment: sex               : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... / Language3         : Factor w/ 3 levels "english","l2_like",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... / vowel             : Factor w/ 3 levels "back","high",..: 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 3 ... / sdev_Mid          : num  1686 1000 1187 1420 1543 ...

Comment: hrbrmstr, like the above? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are thinking? Using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat<-data.frame(express=rep(c("Same Expres.","Diff. Expres."), each=4), 
                gaze=rep(c("Same Gaze","Different Gaze"),each=2), 
                identity=rep(c("Same Identity","Different Identity"),4), 
                val=rnorm(8))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=express, y=val, group=identity))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge",aes(fill=identity))+
  facet_wrap(  ~ gaze)+
  labs(y="% Correct Responses (+ 1SEM)", x="Expression", fill="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

If you wanted to use a box-plot rather than bar chart, use the below

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=express, y=val, group=identity))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=identity))+
  facet_wrap(  ~ gaze)+
  labs(y="% Correct Responses (+ 1SEM)", x="Expression", fill="")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: Yes, it is something like this, but I think Peter's comment is also useful. Do you have any idea how I can do the parallel box plot instead of bar chart?

Comment: the new code bit at the end should get you that. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi JPC, I have tried it, and it says "> data.frame <- read.delim("VL_labiodental.txt", fileEncoding="UTF-16")
> dat<-data.frame(vowel=rep(c("Back vowel","High vowel", "Low vowel"), each=6), 
+                 sex=rep(c("Female","Male"),each=2), 
+                 Language3=rep(c("English","L2","Thai"),6), 
+                 val=rnorm(12))
Error in data.frame(vowel = rep(c("Back vowel", "High vowel", "Low vowel"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 18, 4, 12" Do you have any idea what happens? I am not sure about each number at the end of each line though.

Comment: yes. R can perform vector extensions when the longer vector is a multiple of the shorter, for example the following works: data.frame(c1=1:4,c2=1:2) but this fails data.frame(c1=1:4,c2=1:3). The data.frame dat that you are defining above has this issue. Your vowel vector is of length 18, your sex of length 4. For example if you were to just keep vowel and Language3 in the above it would no longer cause this error

Comment: Oh, yeah the problem is that my vowel has 3; Language has 3, and sex has 2, and that is probably why I cannot do it. I think I might do the bar chart with error bar in excel instead. Thanks very much for your help anyway.

Comment: You can certainly do it, just need to make sure each column of your resulting dataframe has the same length (or can be extended to the same length). I use excel a fair bit and have found anything beyond a basic graphic is worth doing in R. There is nothing nicer than only needing a couple of keystrokes to make significant changes in your graphics (not to mention the ease of sharing and recreating later).

Comment: I have carefully tried to cound the number of column but it still does not work...

Comment: if it's possible for you to post your data, then I'm happy to try and help.

Comment: Yes sure. How can I post my data? Can I send it to your email?

Comment: depending on how large it is, you could use the `dput` command and paste this as part of your original post (that way more people are likely to help as well).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50659/discussion-between-jpc-and-user3288202)

Comment: Sorry I can't add the output from dput command to the original post as it exceeds the number of words (there are around 70000 words), but I did post it to your discussion in chat and it seems like it works.